# "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403" When trying to webscrape in R (2022)

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I've looked at all the other answers to this error from other posts and none of them have solved my issue.

I'm trying to read the html data from this website in various ways:

```
curl::curl("https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities") %>% read_html() 
url <- 'https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities'
url('https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities', "rb")
```

And they all give me the forbidden error. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
url <- "https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(5)
doc <- IEApp$Document()
page_Content <- doc$documentElement()$innerHtml()
html <- read_html(page_Content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that can be considered :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities"
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)
page_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
html <- read_html(page_Content)
```